# Need device independent bitmap bits

Tags: winapi, getdibits

I'm building a dll in C++ to be imported into a VB project.  The dll exposes a function that will extract the preview image of a specified document through the Win Shell, and then writes it into a buffer to be used by the VB app.

So far, I'm able to get the HBITMAP handle without issue.  I was also able to extract the bitmap data using the GetBitmapBits function.  However, this will not work as the object that requires the bit data needs it to be in a device independent format.

I've read that GetDiBits is the function to use for this purpose, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to call the function successfully.

What device context should I be using?  Also, how can I ensure that it writes out the data in device independent format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, I made some progress on this project.  I found a secondary help document about the GetDiBits function (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74601). The api documentation did not explain at all that there is a check list that is performed on the header structure.  So now that that is out of the way, I was able to execute the function successfully and extract some bitmap data.

Comment: Now the problem I have is apparently the device context or something else.  I am testing my code with a 100x100 pixel image with 24-bit colors.  The size of the data extracted using GetDiBits was exactly what was expected for an image of that size.  However, a DIB is supposed to have extra data such as headers and what not so that it can be passed between devices.  So perhaps I am not even using the correct function for this?  

As a reminder, I need to pass the DIB data to an object in a vb project.

Answer (score 0):

If your HBITMAP references a device dependent bitmap, and you need device independent bits, you have to convert them.  Try creating a CImage and call the BitBlt method to put device independent bits in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the device context s still throwing me off.